# Matlab. Find the indices of a cell array of strings with characters all contained in a given string (without repetition)

Tags: string, matlab, find, character, cell-array

I have one string and a cell array of strings.

```
str = 'actaz';
dic = {'aaccttzz', 'ac', 'zt', 'ctu', 'bdu', 'zac', 'zaz', 'aac'};
```

I want to obtain:

```
idx = [2, 3, 6, 8];
```

I have written a very long code that:

1. finds the elements with length not greater than length(str);
2. removes the elements with characters not included in str;
3. finally, for each remaining element, checks the characters one by one

Essentially, it's an almost brute force code and runs very slowly. I wonder if there is a simple way to do it fast.

NB: I have just edited the question to make clear that characters can be repeated n times if they appear n times in str. Thanks Shai for pointing it out.

Comment: does `'aac'` is a valid match for you? `'a'` appears twince in `str`?

Comment: You can do only step 3. and remove the characters that appears in `dic` from `str`, one by one. I soppose there is also some way to do it with `intersect`,`setxor`, `ismember`, etc. ...

Comment: Yes, 'aac' is valid because str has two 'a'.

Comment: I have tried to use ismember and intersect, but I haven't been able to find a solution. Anyway, step 3 is a quite slow piece of code, unless there is a way to vectorialize it.

Comment: @P0W: 'zac' is valid (6th element); 'zaz' is not valid (7th element).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the strings and then match them using regular expression. For your example the pattern will be `^a{0,2}c{0,1}t{0,1}z{0,1}$`:

```
u = unique(str);
t = ['^' sprintf('%c{0,%d}', [u; histc(str,u)]) '$']; 
s = cellfun(@sort, dic, 'uni', 0);
idx = find(~cellfun('isempty', regexp(s, t)));
```

Comment: Mohsen, your solution is the best I have tried so far: correct, elegant and surprisingly fast. Chapeau!

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this :

```
>> g=@(x,y) sum(x==y) <= sum(str==y); 
>> h=@(t)sum(arrayfun(@(x)g(t,x),t))==length(t);
>> f=cellfun(@(x)h(x),dic);
>> find(f)

ans =

     2     3     6
```

- g  & h: check if number of count of each letter in search string <= number of count in `str`.
- f : finally use g and h for each element in `dic`

Comment: It's elegant and it works correctly. I just wonder why it is so slow, just a little faster than mines. My variable dic is very big, ~60K rows - do you think I should write a mex file? Anyway, P0W, your code answers my question. Thank you a lot for that.